# Tensorflow won't matmul inputs and weights. "Dimensions must be equal"

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, valueerror

I've been working on a simple tensor flow neural network.  My input placeholder is

`x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 52000, 3])`.

My weight matrix is initialized to all zeros as

`W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([52000, 10]))`.

I tried different combinations with and without the 3 for color channels, but I guess I'm just not understanding the dimensionality because I got the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Everybody\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\common_shapes.py",
>   line 686, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
>       input_tensors_as_shapes, status)   File "C:\Users\Everybody\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py",
>   line 473, in **exit**
>       c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status)) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shape
>   must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input
>   shapes: [?,52000,3], [52000,10].
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "rating.py", line 65, in
>   
>       y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b # "fake" outputs to train/test   File "C:\Users\Everybody\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py",
>   line 1891, in matmul
>       a, b, transpose_a=transpose_a, transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)   File
>   "C:\Users\Everybody\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py",
>   line 2436, in _mat_mul
>       name=name)   File "C:\Users\Everybody\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py",
>   line 787, in _apply_op_helper
>       op_def=op_def)   File "C:\Users\Everybody\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 2958, in create_op
>       set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)   File "C:\Users\Everybody\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 2209, in set_shapes_for_outputs
>       shapes = shape_func(op)   File "C:\Users\Everybody\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 2159, in call_with_requiring
>       return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)   File "C:\Users\Everybody\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\common_shapes.py",
>   line 627, in call_cpp_shape_fn
>       require_shape_fn)   File "C:\Users\Everybody\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\common_shapes.py",
>   line 691, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
>       raise ValueError(err.message) ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,52000,3],
>   [52000,10].

At first, I thought my `next_batch()` function was the culprit because I had to make my own due to the fact that I uploaded my images "manually" using `scipy.misc.imread()`, whose definition reads:

```
q = 0
def next_batch(batch_size):
    x = images[q:q + batch_size]
    y = one_hots[q:q + batch_size]
    q = (q + batch_size) % len(images)
    return x, y
```

However, after looking through, I don't see what's wrong with this, so I imagine that I'm just confused about dimensionality.  It is supposed to be a "flattened" 200x260 color image.  It just occurred to me now that maybe I have to flatten the color channels as well? I will place my full code below if curious.  I'm a bit new to Tensorflow, so thanks, all.  (Yes, it is not a CNN yet, I decided to start simple just to make sure I'm importing my dataset right.  And, I know it is tiny, I'm starting my dataset small too.)

```
############# IMPORT DEPENDENCIES ####################################

import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession() #start session
import scipy.misc
import numpy as np

######################################################################


#SET UP DATA #########################################################

images = []
one_hots = []

###########  IMAGES ##################################################

#put all the images in a list
for i in range(60):
    images.append(scipy.misc.imread('./shoes/%s.jpg' % str(i+1)))
    print("One image appended...\n")

#normalize them, "divide" by 255
for image in images:
    print("One image normalized...\n")
    for i in range(260):
        for j in range(200):
            for c in range(3):
                image[i][j][c]/=255

for image in images:
    tf.reshape(image, [52000, 3])


########################################################################


################# ONE-HOT VECTORS ######################################

f = open('rateVectors.txt')
lines = f.readlines()

for i in range(0, 600, 10):
    fillerlist = []
    for j in range(10):
        fillerlist.append(float(lines[i+j][:-1]))
    one_hots.append(fillerlist)
    print("One one-hot vector added...\n")

########################################################################3

#set placeholders and such for input, output, weights, biases
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 52000, 3])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([52000, 10]))  # These are our weights and biases
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))         # initialized as zeroes.


#########################################################################


sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) #initialize variables in the session

y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b # "fake" outputs to train/test


##################### DEFINING OUR MODEL  ####################################


#our loss function
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y, y_))

#defining our training as gradient descent
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)


######################  TRAINING #############################################


####################  OUR CUSTOM BATCH FUNCTION ##############################

q = 0
def next_batch(batch_size):
    x = images[q:q + batch_size]
    y = one_hots[q:q + batch_size]
    q = (q + batch_size) % len(images)
    return x, y

#train
for i in range(6):
  batch = next_batch(10)
  train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})
  print("Batch Number: " + i + "\n")

print("Done training...\n")

################  RESULTS  #################################################

#calculating accuracy
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

#print accuracy
print(accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: images, y_: one_hots}))
```

Comment: your placeholder should look like `x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 200, 260, 3])` where `None` is the batch size, `(200,260)` is the image size, and `3` is the color channels

Answer (score 0):

Your placeholder should have the dimension `[None, 200, 260, 3]` where `None` is the batch size, `200, 260` is the image size, and `3` is the channels.

Your weights should be `[filter_height, filter_width, num_channels, num_filters]`

Your bias should be `[num_filters]`

And the dimensions for the labels should be `[None, num_classes]` where `None` is the batch size, and `num_classes` is the number of classes that your images have.

These are just to make sure that math works.

I took these codes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48612987/cannot-improve-accuracy-of-alexnet-on-oxford-102-tensorflow)

Comment: I'm sort of confused about what the `num_filters` is.  Is that only for CNN's?  Would it be, [200, 260, 3, 10] for my weights?  I'm getting errors that Dimension 1 is not equal for my inputs (shape: [None, 200, 260, 3]) and my weights (shape: [200, 260, 3, 10]).  It says that Dimension 1, 200, 260 do not match.  Any ideas?

Comment: I recommend you reading [this](https://adeshpande3.github.io/adeshpande3.github.io/A-Beginner%27s-Guide-To-Understanding-Convolutional-Neural-Networks/) article.